# vitae package and pandoc reference problem

Tags: r, lua, r-markdown, pandoc-citeproc

I am trying to make a CV with vitae package and I find the following example on Github.

https://github.com/HanZhang-psych/CV

How do I get those .bib files like shown in the repository. If I get them, do I put them locally on my computer or should I put it on Github? I am using the windows system.

How do I read these publications' data with vitae package so that I can make a section called publications?

Lastly, I tried to directly knit the rmd file without any changes. However, I got the following error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Error running filter multiple-bibliographies.lua:
multiple-bibliographies.lua: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted